# Accessing secured JAX-WS EJB webservice

Tags: web-services, ejb, jax-ws, basic-authentication, java-ee-7

How do I access this secure Soap webservice implemented by an EJB:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"Boss"})
@WebService(name="SoapService", serviceName="SoapWS", portName="SoapWSPort")
public class SoapServiceImpl implements SoapService {

    @RolesAllowed({"Boss"})
    public SoapThing getSoapThing(String name, String prepend) throws SoapThingyException {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the web.xml has this:

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>         
     <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I created a SoapHandler for the client, to add an Authorization header to the request, like this:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    try {
        String credential = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Map<String, Object> httpHeaders = null;
        if (context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS) != null) {         
            httpHeaders = (Map<String, Object>)context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        } else {
            httpHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        }       
        httpHeaders.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic " + credential.substring(0, credential.length()-1)));
        context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
        return true;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My client is a standalone java app, using stubs generated with wsimport, and adds the handler to the BindingProvider:

```
SoapWS service = new SoapWS();      
SoapService port = service.getSoapWSPort();
((BindingProvider)port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(Arrays.asList(new CredentialHandler("spike", "*****")));
SoapThing st = port.getSoapThingByNumber(1);
```

...it executes fine, adding the credentials to the Authorization header but I'm still getting an unauthorised response from the server:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized
```

The webservice is deployed on Wildfly and the user is assigned to the ApplicationRealm, role Administator, groups Dog and Boss:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic authentication in a JAX-WS client is easier than that:

```
SoapWS service = new SoapWS();      
SoapService port = service.getSoapWSPort();
Map<String,Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

SoapThing st = port.getSoapThingByNumber(1);
```

No handlers required.

The JAX-WS client machinery deals with the HTTP 401 challenge automatically.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. I thought a handler would be the right place to put this bit of code though, but OK.

Comment: As it is BASIC authentication the server does not look at the message payload at all.